# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server - httpd.service failed

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I am trying to configure OTRS on CENTOS, but, the result is that the http.service "Failed to start".

Here is the terminal command that I am executing and the resulting output:

```
# systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

---

Here is the output of `systemctl status httpd.service`:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sáb 2018-02-10 11:23:45 -02; 2min 36s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 1634 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1632 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1632 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local kill[1634]: kill: cannot find process ""
Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Fev 10 11:23:45 srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

---

Here is the output of `hostnamectl status`:

```
Static hostname: srv-lim-otrs02.ttglog.local 
Icon name: computer-vm 
Chassis: vm 
Machine ID: 63206643a78746928a1689f943422fe2 
Boot ID: 4260f7fbdda34149b1ec68d5092da71e 
Virtualization: microsoft 
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) 
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7 
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 Architecture: x86-64
```

---

The following error (from last Saturday) appears in the log file:

```
[Mon Feb 12 10:01:42.618213 2018] [perl:error] [pid 1002] Can't locate DateTime.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /opt/otrs/Custom /opt/otrs/Kernel/cpan-lib /opt/otrs/ /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl line 72.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl line 72.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 1.\n
```

---

Note that I have tried using `cpan> install DateTime` to install this module; but, as you can see, the error persists.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Look into the logfiles in `/var/log/httpd/`.

Comment: Follow the _other_ instruction from the very first error message, as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve with the command below:

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install perl-DateTime-TimeZone*
```

Comment: Do you know why? Could you further elaborate the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This command:
yum --enablerepo=epel install perl-DateTime-TimeZone*

returned the following error for me:
Error: Unknown repo: 'epel'

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423449)